# Converting normalised CIELAB image tensor to RGB image

Tags: opencv, image-processing, pytorch, tensor, color-space

I trained an image to image translation model on pytorch and the input and output images are in CIELAB color space. How do I convert this to an RGB image? Simply converting the image causes some sort of clipping and produces white patches.

```
out=model.forward(x)
out=torch.squeeze(out)
out=out.permute(1,2,0)
out=torch.from_numpy(out.data.numpy())
plt.imshow(out)
```

This doesn't produce white patches however I cant use OpenCV and convert it to RGB as the values are in range 0-1.

[image: CIELAB image in 0-1 range]

Now if I convert the tensor to a PIL image and then convert to RGB(0-255) some sort of clipping occurs and produces white patches which are even visible before converting to RGB

```
out=model.forward(x)
out=torch.squeeze(out)
out=np.asarray(transforms.ToPILImage()(out))
plt.imshow(out)
```

[image: CIELAB with white patches]

The white patches after using `out=cv2.cvtColor(out, cv2.COLOR_LAB2RGB)` to convert

[image: White patches in RGB]

How can I properly convert the CIELAB image to RGB?

Comment: Using this: https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.color.html#skimage.color.lab2rgb

Comment: I tried this, it is messing with the RGB content and the image appears red after conversion

Comment: I think the problem is with transforms.ToPILImage() which in the process of quantization produces these effects. I don't know any workaround.

Comment: Your network's output should have a predetermined range, shouldn't it? Like `[0, 1]` or `[0, 255]`, so you need to make sure that this is the correct range. I don't think you need PIL here, `out.detach().cpu().numpy()[0].transpose(1, 2, 0)` should give you something sized `HxWx3`. Then you need to check datatype and range...

Comment: If you normalized your Lab images you trained with, then you lost important information of the Lab color space. You would have to undo this normalization first.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I did normalize, I used transforms.ToTensor() which normalises the tensor. How can I undo the normalization? Wouldn't the tensor transformation center and normalise each image separately and that would be irreversible right?

Comment: @CrisLuengo also why would normalization lead to loss of information, in essence, it is just scaling the image right?

Comment: @Jan the model output is in [-1,1] and the mean over the image of each component is more close to 0.5
That command would give me the HxWx3 image however I need to map it to the integer range [0,255] before I can convert the LAB space to RGB space using OpenCV and I tried a linear mapping however that again messes up the RGB content of the image

Comment: The a and b components of Lab have a sign. If you don’t preserve the location of the origin, you lose important information (gray becomes colored). I would hope that you scale all images in exactly the same way for training, otherwise you don’t train for specific colors, only for contrast I guess?

Comment: I'm using OpenCV to load LAB images and it has all l,a,b, ranges in 0-255. However I understand the same problem of losing the origin is still present. It's actually an HDR image generation model(from LDR) so I am training for colour as well.

Comment: @CrisLuengo so if I normalise all images with x/255.0 before training and invert it before displaying it should work right? No information would be lost?

Comment: I would think so, yes. You could also try (x-127)/127. Not sure what is better for your network. As long as you can undo the normalization of the output of the network.

Comment: Great, thanks for the help!